# my dashboard page lisview is overlap when i click on list items in android

Tags: android

this is the code of dashboard page where when i click the list item ..it will overlap one fragment  with other ..iam using navigation drawer activity
In this listview is overlap with recycler view i am sharing one image file also

[this is problem in my app of overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQjRM.png)

```
android


public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    ListView simpleList;
    TextView textView;
    String List[] = {"RELIGION", "CASTE", "SUBCASTE"};

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
       simpleList=root.findViewById(R.id.simplelist);
       textView=root.findViewById(R.id.item);

        mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_lisview,R.id.item, List);

         simpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 adapter.getItem(position);

                 if(position==0)
                 {
                     if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                         fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new ReligionFragment()).commit();
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 if(position==1) {
                     loadFragment(new CasteFragment());
                 }
                 else if(position==2) {

                     loadFragment(new SubCasteFragment());
                 }

             }

         });
         simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);

         return  root;
    }
    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }


    }
```

Comment: In this page i have two way apply in if section directly call fragment manager and another is loadfragment() method...but not get answer yet...please help me to out this i am new in android

Comment: Can I see code inside R.layout.fragment_dashboard, please ?

Comment: yes....//Fragment_dashboard.xml                                                                                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/simplelist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#f00"

    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    />

Comment: Is there only a List view ? Then, what is R.id.container1 ?

Comment: i am taking yesterday framelayout so that framelayout id is R.id .Container1 but it is not work so i remove that FrameLayout

Comment: Okay, that means you have a list view containing 3 items. And you want to open separate fragment after click on each list item, am I correct ?

Comment: yes sir ...absolutely...

Comment: that each fargment containing Recyclerview

Comment: Have you used Navigation Component ? What is your Android Studio Version ?

Comment: Your issue has been solved. Check my answer. Feel free to ask any doubt. Happy coding bro !!!

Comment: 4.0.1 version..i have already navgation component..but i try this

Comment: Then you can easily understand my answer. Let me know about your output Bro.

Comment: My apllication run perfect overlapping issue solve ...thank you sir ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Navigation Component for navigating among fragments which is pretty common in Android now a days. You would have seen navigation folder is created  when you create a new Navigation Drawer Activity or Bottom Navigation Activity in updated android studio versions. Let's look one by one. First things first:

DashboardFragment.java

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
   }
}
```

fragment_dashboard.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_dashboard_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/dashboard_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now create a file having name dashboard_navigation inside your navigation folder.

dashboard_navigation.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dashboard_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/listFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:name="com.pagingdemo.ui.dashboard.ListFragment"
    android:label="fragment_list"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_religionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/religionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_casteFragment"
        app:destination="@id/casteFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_subCasteFragment"
        app:destination="@id/subCasteFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/religionFragment"
    android:name="com.pagingdemo.ui.dashboard.ReligionFragment"
    android:label="fragment_religion"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_religion" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/casteFragment"
    android:name="com.pagingdemo.ui.dashboard.CasteFragment"
    android:label="fragment_caste"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_caste" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/subCasteFragment"
    android:name="com.pagingdemo.ui.dashboard.SubCasteFragment"
    android:label="fragment_sub_caste"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sub_caste" />
```

I have just created 4 fragments. 1st, ListFragment to show Religion, Caste and Sub Caste List. 2nd, ReligionFragment for religion recycler view. 3rd, CasteFragment for caste recycler view. 4th, SubCasteFragment for sub caste recycler view.

See my package name is different from your package name. So if you are copying code then please make sure you have created 4 fragments with correct name then replace in this navigation xml file.
I am just posting onCreateView() code of each of the above mentioned 4 fragments.

ListFragment's onCreateView looks like :

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    String[] list = {"RELIGION", "CASTE", "SUBCASTE"};
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    final ListView simpleList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_dashboard);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_view,R.id.list_item_text_view, list);

    simpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 : {
                    Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(R.id.religionFragment);
                    break;
                }
                case 1 : {
                    Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(R.id.casteFragment);
                    break;
                }
                case 2 : {
                    Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(R.id.subCasteFragment);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

ListFragment's layout i.e fragment_list.xml looks like :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ui.dashboard.ListFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

ReligionFragment's onCreateView looks like :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<String> religionList = new ArrayList();
    religionList.add("Hindu");
    religionList.add("Islam");
    religionList.add("Christianity");
    religionList.add("Budhisism");
    religionList.add("Jainisism");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_religion, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.religion_list_view);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(religionList));
    return view;
}
```

Like wise you could use other two fragments such as CasteFragment and SubCasteFragment along with RecyclerView.

Comment: This is perfect answer sir ..for fragments overlapping issue..

Comment: I am not genius, just a programmer. Anyway if I am capable to solving your problem and if I have time then definitely I will help you. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67986971/how-can-i-set-custom-camera-capture-image-to-grid-view-in-android-studio                           sir check this if possible please

Answer (score 0):

Please set android:background="@color/white" in your XML's Parent widget. it works for  me because always fragment set default color transparent.