# I have issue in android ..I have issue with my recyclerview update and delete

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

....

I am using navigation drawer ...in that my fragment class have a recylerview and in recycler view each record has image button of update and delete when i am clicking on that image button updation and deletion is done successfully...but problem is that when updation is done it restart the fragment ...i dont want to restart the fragment ...the changes reflected on same page what change is required for this...

```js
//ReligionAdapter.class
public class ReligionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReligionViewHolder>
implements Filterable {
        private Context context;
       SQLiteDatabase database;


        private ArrayList<ReligionHelper> list;
        private final ArrayList<ReligionHelper> mArrayList;

        private SQLiteHandler db;

        ReligionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ReligionHelper> listContacts) {
                this.context = context;
                this.list = listContacts;
                this.mArrayList = listContacts;
                  db = new SQLiteHandler(context);

        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public ReligionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_data_layout, parent, false);
                return new ReligionViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ReligionViewHolder holder, int position) {
                final ReligionHelper contacts = list.get(position);
                holder.code.setText(contacts.getId());
                holder.name.setText(contacts.getName());
                holder.createdby.setText(contacts.getCreated_by());
                holder.createddt.setText(contacts.getCreated_dt());
                holder.modifiedby.setText(contacts.getModified_by());
                holder.modifieddt.setText(contacts.getModified_dt());
                holder.editreligion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                editTaskDialog(contacts,view);
                        }
                });
                holder.deletereligion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                db = new SQLiteHandler(view.getContext());
                                db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());
                                ReligionHelper delrel = new ReligionHelper(contacts.getId());

                                deletereligion(delrel);
                                db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());
                          ((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();
                          //  ((Activity)view.getContext()).recreate();

                            view.getContext().startActivity(((Activity) view.getContext()).getIntent());

                        }
                });
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
                return new Filter() {
                        @Override
                        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                                        list = mArrayList;
                                } else {
                                        ArrayList<ReligionHelper> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for (ReligionHelper contacts : mArrayList) {
                                                if (contacts.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
                                                        filteredList.add(contacts);
                                                }
                                        }
                                        list = filteredList;
                                }
                                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                                filterResults.values = list;
                                return filterResults;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                                list = (ArrayList<ReligionHelper>) filterResults.values;
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                };
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return list.size();
        }
        public void editTaskDialog( ReligionHelper contacts,View view) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
                View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_religion, null);

                final EditText catcode = subView.findViewById(R.id.ed1);
                final EditText catname = subView.findViewById(R.id.ed2);
                if (contacts != null) {
                        catcode.setText(contacts.getId());
                        catname.setText(String.valueOf(contacts.getName()));
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Update Religion");
                builder.setView(subView);
                builder.create();
                builder.setPositiveButton("EDIT RELIGION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                final String code = catcode.getText().toString();
                                final String name = catname.getText().toString();
                                String mb="U_1";
                                String md=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

                                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Something went wrong. Check your input values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                        db = new SQLiteHandler(view.getContext());
                                        database =   db.getWritableDatabase();
                                        ReligionHelper up=new ReligionHelper( code,name,mb,md);
                                        db.updateReligion(up,database);
                                        updaterel(up);
                                    ((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();

                                    view.getContext().startActivity(((Activity) view.getContext()).getIntent());
                                }
                        }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Task cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                });
                builder.show();
        }


        public void updaterel(ReligionHelper religionHelper) {

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_UPDATE_RELIGION ,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                }

                        }) {
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                // Posting params to register url
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("CAT_CODE",religionHelper.getId());
                                params.put("CAT_NAME",religionHelper.getName());
                                params.put("MODIFIED_BY",religionHelper.getModified_by());
                                params.put("MODIFIED_DT",religionHelper.getModified_dt());
                                return params;
                        }
                };

                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

        }


        public void deletereligion(ReligionHelper religionHelper) {

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_DELETE_RELIGION, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                                }


                        }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                // Posting params to register url
                                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                params.put("CAT_CODE", religionHelper.getId());
                                return params;
                        }
                };

                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

        }
}
```

....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a method inside your adapter class to update item. New method `updateItem()` for updating item and `deleteItem()` for deleting item just below `getItemCount()` method inside adapter class. Like below:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
// For updating item 
private void updateItem(int position, ReligionHelper updatedReligionHelper){
    list.set(position, updatedReligionHelper);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
// For deleting item
private void deleteItem(int position){
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Then call this method after Okay button clicked in edit dialog. I have made changes to your dialog click listener, it looks like :

```
    public void editTaskDialog(int clickedItemPosition, ReligionHelper contacts, View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_religion, null);

    final EditText catcode = subView.findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    final EditText catname = subView.findViewById(R.id.ed2);
    if (contacts != null) {
        catcode.setText(contacts.getId());
        catname.setText(String.valueOf(contacts.getName()));
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Update Religion");
    builder.setView(subView);
    builder.create();
    builder.setPositiveButton("EDIT RELIGION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final String code = catcode.getText().toString();
            final String name = catname.getText().toString();
            String mb="U_1";
            String md=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Something went wrong. Check your input values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
// assigning updated value to the existing object from edit text
                contacts.code = code;
                contacts.name = name;
                contacts.mb = mb;
                contacts.md = md;
                // Update this item in Recycler view now
                updateItem(clickedItemPosition,contacts);
                db = new SQLiteHandler(view.getContext());
                database =   db.getWritableDatabase();
                ReligionHelper up=new ReligionHelper( code,name,mb,md);
                db.updateReligion(up,database);
                updaterel(up);
                //((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();

                //view.getContext().startActivity(((Activity) view.getContext()).getIntent());
            }
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Task cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

And open this dialog like this :->

```
        holder.editreligion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editTaskDialog(position,contacts,view);
        }
    });
```

Delete method from adapter is called while button click like below :->

```
        holder.deletereligion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            db = new SQLiteHandler(view.getContext());
            db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());
            //ReligionHelper delrel = new ReligionHelper(contacts.getId());

            deletereligion(contacts);
            db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());

            // Delete this item from Recycler view---------------------------
            deleteItem(position);
            //((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();
            //  ((Activity)view.getContext()).recreate();

            //view.getContext().startActivity(((Activity) view.getContext()).getIntent());

        }
    });
```

Comment: sir perfect answer it works...Thank you ..what change can do for delete...

Comment: I have update my answer for delete item. You can check it out my friend. Cheers!!!

Comment: Sir thank you so much i am dealing with this from last week ...it is working now ..thanks for your guidance..

Comment: Sir please  see this link also ...https://stackoverflow.com/q/66812096/15483718                 It was very serious issue for me My Main Drawer  opening page is overlap the fragments

Answer (score 0):

**use notifyDataSetChanged(); use to refresh adapter after delete item** no need to open activity and fragment again

```
holder.deletereligion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                db = new SQLiteHandler(view.getContext());
                                db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());
                                ReligionHelper delrel = new ReligionHelper(contacts.getId());

                                deletereligion(delrel);
                                db.deleteReligion(contacts.getId());
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                list.remove(position);
                               

                        }
                });
```

Comment: No change it will delete the value but changes are made after when i restart my app

Comment: i have edit my answer please copy past and check

Comment: please give me some idea for this because i am remove the activity tag...and only use notifydatasetchanged() but it not work ..

Comment: you need to delete item sqlite and list also

Comment: i am using same ,copy and paste on my studio...no change

Comment: yes from list as well as sqlite database and from my server also...

Answer (score 0):

Remove data from both from your arraylist and than notify your list will update.

recyclerView.remove(getAdapterPosition());

notifyDataSetChanged();

//or use this for better perfomance.
notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());

Pass position in remove method

Comment: i am not getting that adapter position in my code...how can i get the getAdapterPosition() in my code because it has error