# How can I set custom camera capture image to grid view in android studio

Tags: android, gridview, image-capture

I am developing an app for custom camera and custom gallery. My image capturing is done very well but not set to grid view. What mistake did I do in my code? How can I set capture image to my grid view and how that image path  will pass to next?

```
//Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Camera camera;
    ImageView imageView ;
FrameLayout frameLayout;
showCamera showCamera;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    50); }

        // Create an instance of Camera
        camera = getCameraInstance();

        showCamera=new showCamera(this,camera);
        frameLayout.addView(showCamera);
        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.captureFront);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                         CaptureImage(v);
                        File file = getOutputMediaFile();
                        Log.e("use_pic buttn ", file.getPath());
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("output", file.getPath());
                    }
                }
        );
        Button gallarybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gallary);
        gallarybutton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomGallary.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                }
        );
    }
    Camera.PictureCallback mpictureCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File picture_file = getOutputMediaFile();
            if(picture_file== null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(picture_file);
                    fos.write(data);
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };

        private File getOutputMediaFile() {
            String state= Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if(!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            {
                return null;
            }
        else
            {
             File folder_gui= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "GUI");

             if(!folder_gui.exists())
             {
                 folder_gui.mkdir();
             }
             File outputFile= new File(folder_gui,"temp.jpg");
             return  outputFile;

            }
        }


    public void CaptureImage(View v)
    {
        if(camera!=null)
        {
          camera.takePicture(null,null,mpictureCallback);
        }
    }
    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    
}
```

In this code I have an error: My grid view is not set image capture by custom camera

```
//CustomGallary.java


public class CustomGallary extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("output");
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        bitmapArray.add(bitmap); // Add a bitmap
        //bitmapArray.get(0); // Get first bitmap

        GridView mygrid=findViewById(R.id.gv);
        ImageView iv=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Log.e("Helloo", String.valueOf(bitmap));
        ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(this,R.layout.gv_item, bitmapArray);
          mygrid.setAdapter(adapter);





    }
}
```

Comment: Someone help me to sort the problem of this

Comment: No info about showCamera ??? It would be better if you add xml code also.